# Transition from ErrorT to ExceptT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

A recent cabal install upgraded my version of [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0) from [0.3.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0) to [0.4.1.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0).  With this upgrade came depreciation warnings about ErrorT.

The documentation is not clear is this just a renaming or is there a functional change? Why was this change made?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a functional change. [`ErrorT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#t:ErrorT) demands that the `e` type be a member of the [`Error` type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#t:Error)—for example, consider its `Monad` instance constraints. This is fairly arbitrary and certainly not needed for the functionality of `ErrorT`.

[`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT) lifts this restriction.

The renaming was introduced in order to create a more smooth upgrade pathway. People who currently use and depend upon the `Error` constraint in their `ErrorT` stacks should not have to change code. People who'd like to use the strictly more general `ExceptT` module can freely choose to do so. At some point the `ErrorT` module may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a change in the semantics.

`ErrorT e m` expects that `e` implements the `Error` class in its `Monad` instance.  This allows the implementation of `fail` for `ErrorT e m` to throw an exception:

```
fail msg = ErrorT $ return (Left (strMsg msg))
```

In contrast, `ExceptT` does not make any such restriction.  Instead the implementation of `fail` for `ExceptT e m` calls the exception in the underlying monad `m`:

```
fail = ExceptT . fail
```

I prefer `ErrorT`'s behavior since it allows me to catch any instance where `fail` is called by code over a generic monad.  In any case, it's important to review your code before blinding renaming `ErrorT` to `ExceptT`.

Comment: An ye ne'er call `fail`, ye'll ne'er encounter this difficulty.

Comment: This is simply not true.  GHC also implicitly calls fail when ever a pattern match fails:

Comment: As a side note, I write a lot of Haskell code, and I tend to often use the typechecker to catch errors.  For better or worse, fail is a part of Monad.

I think its terrible for a library maintainer to issue deprecation warnings recommending changes that will silently break application code because they changed the semantics of an operation in a subtle and poorly documented way.